# PHP File Size Limit Message

Tags: php, apache

We are using `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` PHP variables to prevent users from uploading big files into our web app.

The thing is that the error message that PHP throws is ugly for the users and does not say much (especially for spanish users). So the users report this as a bug or think it is not working.

How can I change this page and show our own page (something more user friendly and in Spanish)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [set_error_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

So something along the lines of (from the manual):

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Answer (score 0):

catch the error and output a custom message.

```
 try {
    // your code
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    if($e->getCode() == some code){
        $message = 'some message';
    }else{
        $message = 'some other message';
    }
 }

 echo '<div>'.$message.'</div>'
```